# Outlook 365 Add-in send event

Tags: javascript, office365, office-addins

Is there a way to catch the 'send' button click event using javascript? I'm not using the VSTO, i'm using the App for Office project in visual studio.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the Office Javascript library does not support the Send event. Here is the relevant page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142177.aspx

Using a different extensibility model, you can access the Outlook Desktop's object model from HTML & Javascript:

https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2014/11/26/access-outlook-html-javascript-addins/

Maybe this strategy can suit your use case?

Ty